# Передача переменного из файла .sh в файл конфигурации .conf

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Как можно передать значение переменного в файл конфигурации? Нужно, чтобы скрипт определил имя беспроводного интерфейса и передал его файлам конфигурации hostapd и dnsmasq.

Comment: Изменить содержимое файла?

Comment: @SlavaSemushin скажем в строке interface=name, а name решается в одном скрипте прежде, чем вызвать эти службы. Такое возможно?

Comment: `sed -ri "s/^(interface=).*/\1$var/" файл`. двойные кавычки — ключевой момент.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а как сделать, чтобы пробела не было? В файле hostapd.conf это косяк.

Comment: @Timeon, про какой пробел речь?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin файл становится таим interface= wlan0 . То есть между знаком "=" и "wlan0" не должно быть пробелов.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin извиняюсь, пробел в переменном возника из за другой команды, все работает

Comment: @Timeon, судя по всему, пробел вы сохраняете внутри переменной. но пробелы можно принудительно убрать прямо в предлагаемой программе для интерпретатора `sed -ri "s/^(interface=).*/\1$var/;/^interface=/s/ //g" файл`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NAME="interface"     # имя переменной
VALUE="name"         # значение переменной
FileName="file.conf" # конфигурационный файл
awk -i inplace -v N=$NAME -v V=$VALUE -F" = |=| =|= " 'BEGIN{OFS="="} ($1==N) {$2=V} 1' $FileName
```

Answer (score 0):

В dnsmasq имя интерфейса убираешь из конфига и добавляешь в аргументы коммандной строки. Все параметры из конфига можно задать аргументами в dnsmasq.

Для hostapd я конфигурировал конфиг полностью по шаблону, потом сохранил в /var/run/ .